# Power BI star (constellation) schema: 2 fact tables with relation between each other

Tags: powerbi, data-warehouse, star-schema, fact-table

I need to create a data warehouse for analyzing data in an order process but I am unsure of how to proceed since my research led to conflicting information. For simplicity I will only use the most important tables to describe my issue.

*TblOrder (Fact)*:

- Once a customer makes an order it creates an entry in *TblOrder*.
- Every entry is unique an has an *OrderNo*and it's own timestamp of creation

*TblOrderSubProcess (Fact)*:

- An order consists of at least 1 sub process.
- Each sub process of an order is a unique entry in *TblOrderSubProcess* and has it's own timestamp of creation.
- Each sub process contains has a column with the *OrderNo*
- An entry will only be made if enough material is in the warehouse
- Moving material between warehouses (for storage management) is also a sub process but has *OrderNo = null*

*TblOrderInformation (Dimension)*:

- This table contains information about how a sub process is supposed to be executed (e.g.: locationA → locationB, material, expected time, etc.)

[image]

Star schema being the best practise in Power BI, I am not supposed to create a relationship between *TblOrder* and *TblOrderSubProcess* but there will be visuals which need the relation between both tables.

My solution to this was to create a flat table where I *TblOrder* LEFT JOIN *TblOrderSubProcess*. This solution works but has it's flaws:

- If I create a date slicer it will always be using the date of Order or OrderSubProcess. This would mean that my Power BI Reports can only contain information of either Order or OrderSubProcess
- Joining the tables creates redundancies

  - I would still need a seperate Table for all the OrderSubProcesses which were created because of storage management since I would lose these entries in a LEFT JOIN (because *OrderNo* = null)
- The created flat table would be very large with initially 30 columns. The columns will grow over time.

My goal is a datamodel which solves the mentioned issues and follows best practises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very similar to the order header - order line data modeling problem. The kimball group wrote a blog post about this below.

https://www.kimballgroup.com/2007/10/design-tip-95-patterns-to-avoid-when-modeling-headerline-item-transactions/

In summary, TblOrderSubProcess will be your fact table. TblOrder would be split into logical dimensions.

Comment: Okay so my solution would be:
 - TblOrderSubProcess would become my fact table
 - TblOrder would be split into logical dimensions and the fact information would become part of TblOrderSubProcess

Now this solution makes sense to me but how would I avoid the issue with having multiple date timestamps. Power BI only allows me to have a specific date per slicer. How can I manage to have a slicer which can match both creation date of order and creation date of sub process at the same time?

Comment: You should create (in every report really) what is called a date table. It guides all the time intelligence in your report. You would relate this new date table to both the order and subprocess table. Here's an example date table you can add by adding a blank query and pasting this M code into the advanced editor. You should also 'Mark as a date table' in Power Bi after the table has loaded.
https://github.com/dataDad/M-Code-Power-Query/blob/main/Script-for-Date-Dimension%20(1).txt

Comment: @zach I understand what you are saying but my question is a different one. If I have a date table and multiple date columns in my table. And I need to use different date columns based on diagrams, how would I be able to do that with a single date table? Since there can only be 1 active connection at a time in power bi

Comment: we build the relationship based on the date field that makes the most sense. For example I may have a table with shipping information. The default relationship is with the shipdate column. However , if I want metrics based on another column like orderDate, i can create an inactive relatoinship, and then create a measure with the USERELATIONSHIP function. That is generally how the modeling is done. You can have several inactive relationships.